# Calling detectChanges() inside ngAfterViewChecked

Tags: angular, angular-changedetection

Will there be an issue if I call `ChangeDetectorRef.detectChanges()` inside of `ngAfterViewChecked`?

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-weiou4?file=src/app/hello.component.ts

**AppComponent**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular ' + VERSION.major;
  childName = 'Child';

  constructor(private cd: ChangeDetectorRef) {}

  ngAfterViewChecked() {
    this.cd.detectChanges()
  }
}
```

**HelloComponent**

```
export class HelloComponent {
  @Input() name: string;

  constructor(private parent: AppComponent) {}

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.parent.name = "Not";
  }
}
```

Since I'm modifying the parent component's property from the child component in `AfterViewInit`, it will give the "Expression has changed..." error. But if I am to add the `detectChanges()` in the parent component's 'AfterViewChecked`, the error will go away since the change always get detected.

Is there a problem with this approach?

In dev. mode, the change detection is called twice anyways, so aren't I just enabling that in production as well by doing this?

### Edit

I am aware of alternatives to this approach but I am actually curious about the drawbacks of this approach. Like if it's likely to have issues or infinite loops.

Comment: you can store your property in the service and use it in both places? or you can emit output event from child component with the value which should be added to the parent component property

Answer (score 0):

It is a hacky solution, it might break down the line because it might be undefined behaviour. Angular docs suggest using `setTimeout` or similar methods...

I like the suggestion from @AshotAleqsanyan of using a service to share changes between the parent and child components. Alternatively use the `(changeName)` output to change the name.

---

> ### [`DetectChanges` (link)](https://angular.io/api/core/ChangeDetectorRef#detectchanges)
>
> Checks this view and its children. Use in combination with detach to implement local change detection checks.